# Best practices on common person fields (Name, email, address, gender etc...)

Tags: database-design, best-practices

What are the most common best practices on length and data type on common fields like:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Address
- Email
- Sex
- State
- City
- Country
- Phone Number

etc....

Comment: This question is WAYYY to broad. It should be purged and deleted.

Comment: Related: [What problems are solved by splitting street addresses into individual columns?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133636/36809)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I would tend to be very suspicious of any set of universal best practices because, for most of these fields, the devil is in the details.  Just because the information is relatively common doesn't mean that your application uses the data in exactly the same way that other applications use it.  That means your data model may need to be slightly different.

- First & last name: Why are you capturing the name?  If you have a requirement to capture a person's full legal name (i.e. you are preparing legal documents or birth certificates), you probably want to allow more space for people to type than you would if you're just asking for a person's name so you have something to call them in your new web app.
- Address: What are you going to do with the address?  What sort of addresses are you storing?  If you are storing the address of a property in the United States that you're creating a mortgage on, you likely care very much about getting a fully standardized address in which case the data model will probably want to hew very closely to whatever your address standardization tool returns.  If you just want people to be able to type in an address to deliver a product, a couple lines for freeform text is probably sufficient.  The length of the lines there may depend on the requirements of the downstream processes that do things like print address labels.
- State: Assuming you can identify the valid state values, it probably makes sense to create a `STATE` table and create a foreign key relationship between the `STATE` and `ADDRESS` tables.  But the ability to identify the valid values implies that you're limiting the set of valid addresses at least to a particular set of countries.  That's fine for many sites but then you've got to do a bit of work to support a new country.
- City: If you are dealing with data where there are potentially city-level regulations in place (i.e. where there are different sorts of tax rates that are applied based on the city), you may want to treat it much like the state and have a `CITY` table with the valid cities and a foreign key relationship between the `CITY` and `ADDRESS` tables.  On the other hand, if you're just trying to get a product delivered and you don't much care if you have various versions of the same city in your table, letting the user free-form enter text is sufficient.  Of course, if you are storing foreign keys, you'll have a fair amount of work to make sure that you have all the valid values.  But there are products where the whole point is that the company has already done that work (i.e. sales tax databases).
- Phone: What are you doing with phone numbers and why?  Some applications will want to take in phone numbers in whatever format the user decides to enter them and preserve that formatting for all subsequent queries.  This would be common if you are designing a personal address book where users have their own preferences for how phone numbers are stored and displayed.  Other applications would want to ignore the formatting that is entered, extract only the numeric characters, and then format the data on retrieval so that all phone numbers have similar formatting.  If you're catering to businesses, you may want a separate field for users to enter an extension.  If you are trying to support an outbound calling process, you may want to store the area code and country code in separate columns because you'll want to make sure that you have time zone specific windows for calling people in different area codes (making a call to someone in the Eastern time zone at 10am is going to go over much better than making that same call to someone in the Pacific time zone where it is 7am).
- Gender: For a great many applications, it's perfectly reasonable to store a gender code ('M' or 'F') in a table.  On the other hand, there are cases when you may want additional options (Other, Intersex, Transgendered) or where you need to store something like the gender at birth and the current gender.

Comment: interesting answer with lots of things to think about - but lacking any useful idea to help people get further... for example the phone thing there is a pretty simple thing that will cover >=80% of cases: the number you can type in somewhere to reach somebody on the phone, maybe with the addition that it should cover other countries as well. so yes, there's a difference of a few characters if you consider a number could be with/without the country prefix, but there defintely *is* a thing like the longest phone number in the world and using this plus a few more is pretty safe for most cases

Answer (score 25):

You may as well *guess* based on sample data and expected audience. It depends on your location.

Some notes:

Addresses:

- I don't have a state and it irritates me when I have to pick "Outside USA"
- UK postal counties bear no resemblance top local government regions: see ["Column type and size for international country subdivisions (states, provinces, territories etc)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637935/column-type-and-size-for-international-country-subdivisions-states-provinces-t/3638587#3638587) on SO where I broke someone's assumptions

Names:

- Don't forget Family name, Given Name, Known As, Tribal name, Patronymic, Generation Name etc
- See ["Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names"](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and then consider crying
- See ["Last Name First"](http://www.solidether.net/article/last-name-first/) and just cry
- SO ["What is the longest human name you can expect?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128099/what-is-the-longest-human-name-you-can-expect/245998#245998) for a worked example

Phone number: International code, length, mobile vs house, allow mobile as only number

Comment: The last two links ("Last Name First" and "What is the longest...") are broken.

Comment: @MarcL. I fixed the "Last Name First" link (if my edit gets accepted). The "What is the longest..." SO questions has been closed as "not constructive" and deleted (you can still see it if you have >10k rep).

Comment: Wayback Machine has the "Last Name First" article:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160823135055/http://www.solidether.net/2008/jul/22/last-name-first/

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the great answers above, don't forget to accept unicode characters.  Just because you are in the US doesn't mean that you don't want to accept foreign characters into your columns.

That said, I usually recommend 50 characters for names.  320 should be more than enough for an email address (you can check the ANSI standard to be sure).  For address error on the side of caution with 255 characters.  While you'll probably never need an address that big, you might if you include C/O lines and stuff like that.  City should be pretty big, there are some pretty long city names out there.  For state go with a child table, same with country.  For Zip code don't forget about international postal codes which are longer than US zip codes.  Just because you don't support international you still might be.  There are lots of US citizens who live in different counties including military folks.

Don't forget that state should be optional as many countries don't have states.

Comment: On my last project, I found a document on international postal standards that indicated 39 as the maximum line length.  France has a separate code for large volume recipients that goes after the city.  I would allow 3 or 4 free format fields of this size plus country.

Answer (score 9):

My bum is getting sore from sitting on the fence, so I am going to just throw out some answers and hope to not get down-voted into oblivion. Please offer constructive criticism.

### E-mail Address:

min: 6 (a@g.cn) . Or 3 if you want to track local domain email addresses
max: <strike>320</strike> 254 (RFC)

The amount of code to validate an email is actually insane, so let's just assume it's valid if it has a "@"

You may want to abstract an email address as a "communication method", so that you can easily list all methods with which to communicate with a user.

### Gender

Gender can change over time, so you could track that if it's important to you. Follow http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218

```
NOT_KNOWN(0),
MALE(1),
FEMALE(2),
NOT_APPLICABLE(9);
```

### Addresses: NORAM

I am gonna take the cheap way out and stick to North American addresses.

It is convenient to abstract countries, divisions, cities, and counties mostly due to taxation. Taxes can apply at many levels, so if you can point a tax rate at an abstract geographic area, you are golden.

**GeographicArea**:

```
id: int  
type: {country, division, county, city, indian reservation}  
name: varchar(45)  [1]
abbreviation: nullable varchar(4)  
parent_id: nullable int
```

**Address**:

```
id: int  
postal_area_id: int, references GeographicArea  
county_or_city_id: int, references GeographicArea  
street_address: varchar(255)  
suite: nullable varchar(255)
```

Add line2, and line3 if you need to.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_(geography)

Now, an address is an address. Multiple people can live at an address, and a person can have multiple addresses at the same time, and over time, so you need a many-many table for that.

**PartyAddress**

```
party_id: int references Party  
address_id: int references Address  
purpose: {home, work, ...}
```

Add a `from_date` and nullable `to_date` if tracking over time.

### Phone Numbers

A party can have multiple phone numbers, and a phone number can be used by multiple people. A phone number can be used for faxes, telephone calls, modems, etc. and can have extensions. These can all change over time too.

**PhoneNumber**

```
id: int  
value: varchar(15) - the max allowed by the ITU
```

The min might be 3 (for "911"), or maybe 7 ("310-4NET", which is a special kind of local number that does not allow you to dial the area code)

You could split this into country code, etc if necessary.

You should use the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164 standard

**PartyPhoneNumber**

```
party_id: int references Party  
phone_number_id references PhoneNumber  
extension: nullable varchar(11) - ITU max  
purpose: {home, work, fax, modem, ...}
```

### Names

Names are tough. Here's why:

1. Some people have a legal name with only one word in it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legally_mononymous_people
2. Some people have names with many words http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe%2B585,_Senior
3. Some people have multiple names at the same time (for example, at my university there are many Asian students, but they like to use "preferred" more Westernized names)
4. Sometimes, you need to track peoples' names over time, such as maiden names and married names.
5. You want to abstract individuals and organizations for a variety of good reasons

   create table party(
     id bigserial primary key
   );

   create table party_name(
     id bigserial primary key,
     party_id bigint not null references party(id),
     type smallint not null references party_name_type(id) --elided, ex "maiden", "legal"
   );

   create table name_component(
     id bigserial primary key,
     party_name_id bigint not null references party_name(id),
     type smallint not null references name_component_type(id), --elided ex "given"
     name text not null
   );

Answer (score 4):

Regarding names, consider using double-quotes so you don't have to escape apostrophes in Irish or Italian names (e.g., O'Hara or D'Amato).

I'd also recommend getting a good set of Regular Expressions to use, so you can output parts of your name fields (e.g., first initial, nickname, Jr/Sr, etc.).

Comment: Or Dutch names such as my surname.

Answer (score 3):

From a slightly different perspective than the previous answers, and since [it seems OK to talk about LDAP](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/is-ldap-on-topic), [RFC 4519 -- "Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP): Schema for User Applications"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519) may be of interest.

It may be useful if your application needs to be mapped to such a directory. Otherwise, it's probably not adapted to your requirements.

These definitions are more than just about data, they're also about some operators that can be used on the fields. [`postalAddress`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#section-2.23), for example is a [`caseIgnoreListSubstringsMatch`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#section-4.2.10). I'm not suggesting that you should adhere to this schema strictly, but looking at the principles could be interesting, in particular how you may have to compare name and addresses in your application may be relevant to the design of your database.